# SimpleCursor adapter Not displaying my rows

Tags: android, listview, row, simplecursoradapter

My app is not displaying my data from my database. I cannot figure out why this is not working because i believe all my setup is properly done. Can anyone help me figure out why my data is not being displayed?

Here is my list view code :

```
 package com.work.plan;

 // multiple imports .... not included for length purpose

 public class WorkoutList extends Activity {

//====================================================================
//  Member variables

private Button addNewWorkout;
private WorkoutDbAdapter mDbHelper;
public static final int CREATE_WORKOUT = 1;
public static final int SET_WORKOUT = 2;
private String dateCreated = null;
private Calendar now = null; 
private SimpleDateFormat format = null;
private ListView myWorkoutList;



Intent prevIntent ;
String woName,userName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workout_list);

    addNewWorkout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewWorkout);
    prevIntent = getIntent();
    userName = prevIntent.getStringExtra("userName");

    // do the work for getting the current time and formatting it
    now = Calendar.getInstance();
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm aaa");
    dateCreated = format.format(now.getTime());

     mDbHelper = new WorkoutDbAdapter(this);
     mDbHelper.open();

     myWorkoutList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.workoutList);
     registerForContextMenu(myWorkoutList);

     myWorkoutList.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.mainDivider));
     myWorkoutList.setDividerHeight(1);
     myWorkoutList.setOnItemClickListener(WorkoutListener);

     addNewWorkout.setOnClickListener(NewWorkout);

    fillData();
}

OnClickListener NewWorkout = new OnClickListener(){
     // ......... click listener code for my add button
     // ......... creates a new workout

};
//===============================================================================
//
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

}
//===============================================================================
//
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mDbHelper.open();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    mDbHelper.close();
}


//================================================================================
//
// Fill the data for UI rebuilds
private void fillData(){

    Log.d("User_NAME",""+ userName);

    Cursor workoutCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllWorkouts();
    startManagingCursor(workoutCursor);

    String [] from = new String [] { WorkoutDbAdapter.KEY_WORKOUT_NAME,
                                    WorkoutDbAdapter.KEY_WORKOUT_CREATED_DATE ,WorkoutDbAdapter.KEY_WORKOUT_TYPE};

    int [] to = new int [] {R.id.dateCreatedLabel, R.id.nameLabel, R.id.typeLabel};

    SimpleCursorAdapter workouts = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.workout_row, workoutCursor, from, to);

    myWorkoutList.setAdapter(workouts);


}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu , View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    //........ stuff for my menu
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    //.......... code for my menu, handles menu clicks
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

}

//================================================================================

OnItemClickListener WorkoutListener = new OnItemClickListener(){

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
            final long id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(WorkoutList.this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.edit)
        .setTitle("Update Selected Workout")
        .setMessage("Would you like to update the current Workout? Click continue to proceed.")
        .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                final Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ExerciseList.class);
                i.putExtra(WorkoutDbAdapter.KEY_ROW_ID, id);
                i.putExtra("workoutName", woName);
                startActivityForResult(i, SET_WORKOUT);

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    }

};
}
```

I then have a database adapter that creates the table 'workouts' in SQLite.

Here is the WorkoutDbAdapter code :

```
public class WorkoutDbAdapter {
//=========================================================================
    // Member Variables

     public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "workouts";            
     public static final String KEY_ROW_ID = "_id";                 
     public static final String KEY_WORKOUT_EMAIL = "email";
     public static final String KEY_WORKOUT_NAME = "workout_name";              
     public static final String KEY_WORKOUT_CREATED_DATE = "created_date";
     public static final String KEY_WORKOUT_TYPE = "type";


     // string query that creates the table in the database
     static final String CREATE_TABLE_WORKOUTS  = ("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("+ KEY_ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                                                                   + KEY_WORKOUT_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                                                                   + KEY_WORKOUT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                                                                   + KEY_WORKOUT_CREATED_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                                                                   + KEY_WORKOUT_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL);");


     private final Context m_ClassContext;                          // reference to the current class
     private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;                              // reference the database helper class
     private SQLiteDatabase mDb;                                    // reference to the SQLiteDatabase class


     // class constructor
     public WorkoutDbAdapter(Context ctx){
         this.m_ClassContext = ctx;
     }

     // open the database with a reference to this class
     public WorkoutDbAdapter open() throws SQLException{
         this.mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(m_ClassContext);
         this.mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
         return this;
     }

     // create a work out
     public long createWorkout(String email, String workoutName, String workoutDate, String workoutType){
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(KEY_WORKOUT_EMAIL, email);
         values.put(KEY_WORKOUT_NAME, workoutName);
         values.put(KEY_WORKOUT_CREATED_DATE, workoutDate);
         values.put(KEY_WORKOUT_TYPE, workoutType);
         long insertValue = this.mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
         return insertValue;

     }

     // delete a Work out
     public boolean deleteWorkout(long rowId){
         return this.mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROW_ID + "=" +rowId,null) > 0;
     }

//**My error was here**
     // fetch allWorkouts for this user
     public Cursor fetchAllWorkouts(String email){
         return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROW_ID,
KEY_WORKOUT_EMAIL, KEY_WORKOUT_NAME, KEY_WORKOUT_CREATED_DATE, KEY_WORKOUT_TYPE},
KEY_WORKOUT_EMAIL+ "='" +email+"'",null,null,null,null); // i removed a null and it works
     }

     // fetch a work out
     public Cursor fetchWorkout(long rowId) throws SQLException{
         Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,new String[]{KEY_ROW_ID,
                    KEY_WORKOUT_EMAIL,KEY_WORKOUT_NAME,KEY_WORKOUT_CREATED_DATE, KEY_WORKOUT_TYPE}, KEY_ROW_ID + "="+rowId, null,null,null,null,null);
         if(mCursor != null){
             mCursor.moveToFirst();
         }
         return mCursor;
     }


     public boolean updateWorkout(long rowId, String email, String workoutName, String createdDate, String workoutType){
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(KEY_WORKOUT_EMAIL, email);
         values.put(KEY_WORKOUT_NAME, workoutName);
         values.put(KEY_WORKOUT_CREATED_DATE, createdDate);
         values.put(KEY_WORKOUT_TYPE, workoutType);


         return this.mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, KEY_ROW_ID +"="+rowId, null)> 0;
     }

     // close the database
     public void close(){
         if(mDbHelper != null){
             mDbHelper.close();
             mDb.close();
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: At first glance everything looks fine, what is the size of `workoutCursor`?

Comment: can u post your WorkoutDbAdapter code. which is connects the database i think so

Comment: the code has been posted take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running into problems with your database code and the cursor size is 0.  Watch logcat for failed sql queries and debug the size of the cursor.

Comment: you were right it was in my database file. I was requesting a where clause but also supplying a null in the position. See my code edit above

Comment: oh and thanks a ton. I thought my simplecursor was the problem even though the same code works in the app somewhere else! brain fart. . THANKS AGAIN!!!